# What are the valid 'settings' key/values for AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: swift, macos, api, dictionary, audio

I'm working on a Swift application for macOS that uses [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder). The [initializer method of this class may consume a 'settings' dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/1388386-init). The relevant AV docs all make an URL-less, plain-text reference to where these settings key/values are defined with statements such as:

> For information on the settings available for an audio recorder, see
>   AV Foundation Audio Settings Constants.

I've searched quite a lot for this document and failed to locate it. I've actually submitted a feedback report to Apple requesting they update their API docs with links to that document as it's referred to in many places, but only by name.

I've tried googling extensively. I've used Apple's own search function on their developer site and I've searched with the API docs within Xcode itself. That effort has not located a document titled *AV Foundation Audio Settings Constants*, but I can find many docs that refer to it by that precise name.

Does anyone out there know where this mystical API doc actually exists?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/general_audio_format_settings

Comment: @the4kman - Thanks for trying, I've looked over that one previously. That it doesn't have the title the other docs refer to, "_AV Foundation Audio Settings Constants_", I'm guessing that's not it.

Comment: I think the title changed and they did not update the doumentation elsewhere.

Comment: @the4kman - That may be so, I kind of expected more settings options than what that discusses. I've tried setting my settings dictionary with values from that and I can't tell that it changes anything, though I do get a crash where I have none if I make the settings object empty.

Answer (score 4):

I've not found any actual authoritative doc on this, here's just a running list of the parameters I've encountered thus far:

`AVFormatIDKey :` `kAudioFormatAppleLossless`, `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`

`AVNumberOfChannelsKey :` `2`

`AVSampleRateKey :` `44100.0`

`AVEncoderBitRateKey:` `192000`, `320000`

`AVEncoderAudioQualityKey :` `AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue`, `AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue`

---

Here's a Swift example of creating a settings dictionary with some of these values:

```
let settings:[String : Any] = [ AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ] as [String : Any]
```

I hope to keep updating this with more options as I go. Others are welcome to update this too, just please follow the format I have here.

Comment: When you use kAudioFormatAppleLossless, you cannot again include AVEncoderAudioQualityKey. Adding the key causes a crash

Comment: Also, I believe when you set `AVEncoderAudioQualityKey` that is basically doing the job of setting `AVEncoderBitRateKey` manually with an integer value. So you can use either one.